Puppeteer: Website not loading specifically for Linux: Headless mode
Getting the page content some websites, does not include the dynamic content loaded by js/fonts/images (only gets the initial doc). This problem does not occur in windows headless or headfull mode, neither does this happen in linux headfull mode. After some debugging I have noticed that, the number of requests are less in headless mode. I have also used stealth mode plugin to bypass stealth detection.
sample code I am using
const stealth = StealthPlugin();
puppeteer.use(stealth);

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  args: [
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--font-render-hinting=none",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--no-first-run",
  ],
});

const page = await browser.newPage();

page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(30 * 1000);
let res = await page.goto(config.pageUrl, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

let pageContent = await page.content();
fs.writeFileSync("output.html", pageContent);


Please share a [mcve].
